# Import account from one geth node to another geth node

Tags: go-ethereum, accounts, addresses, import

I had a geth node where i created an account. Then i backed up the keystore folder just in case. I had to format the pc and install geth again. So i would like to know how can i import my old account address to new geth? Should i just paste the  "UTC..." file from the keystore folder which i had backed up, inside the keystore folder of the new geth? I don't want to mess anything up so i thought it would be a better idea to first ask what i should do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, copy the "UTC.." file to the new keystore directory. If you view the contents of that file you will see everything related to the account e.g.:

{"address":"b36cb35f9df4f2b9e716c66879b5b47feee5d421","crypto":{"cipher":"aes-128-ctr","ciphertext":"098393543a81851a7cb47abf88ed360863b43e97c9265bbcd0a418ffa13b2d96","cipherparams":{"iv":"6a1843b9b640d332b9cc754b44cd6b75"},"kdf":"scrypt","kdfparams":{"dklen":32,"n":262144,"p":1,"r":8,"salt":"6e86c4fc3cd05634ab4b2bf0336c08ee3c1128cb47c7da7b39331f964bac16a8"},"mac":"6785fe08d9b41f43b8da41e25b404d5c2adeb56a1f689de0d67373cc83eb7ef7"},"id":"0ef22ea0-a0ba-4376-90d2-67328c2e553f","version":3}

EDIT: you will still have your account but of course if you created it in a private test network, it won't have funds anymore in a new network :)

Comment: As I notice both the questioner and the answer have little reputation on the site, and I assume this means relative newness to Ethereum, I thought I would just add the kind admonition to be super careful with the private keys as if you damage them or misplace them your Ether coins will be lost, unrecoverably, forever. Sorry if you both already know this, but whenever I make comments related to private keys, I always add this admonition just in case.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Thomas. I am aware of that, the above is a test account, but thanks for mentioning :)