# Importing accounts into geth from metamask

Tags: go-ethereum, metamask, accounts

I Have entered into my geth console

```
geth 

eth.accounts
["0xf844f0d7acb0d01bf66ffd81809fb96b2236abce", "0xc8d94cb87173fc94c4b165e44a5fc0b047618044", "0x6a0ef1a429c3570cb342963d309dd5aaa9e49cd4", "0x21c4910f85842cd6dc2ecb50fc2612b2b0c9e703"]
```

But i coudn't see my metamask account which  metamask gave me first

```
0xC2a7b0DD8e7728C77712EB196fDcF375C3632fA8
```

Address of the metamask given account

I tried to request ether by fosset for test it gave me  3 ether but I can't see it in my console

```
 eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[0])
```

MY metamask test network is having 3 ether so I tried to check the balance in terminal still it gave me 0

```
> eth.getBalance('0xC2a7b0DD8e7728C77712EB196fDcF375C3632fA8')
0
```

1)How to import the metamask account into geth so we can interact with  geth  console

2) Why balance is showing me zero when typing the command even if the balance is present

Answer (score 0):

You can import your account into geth using this command `geth account import <keyfile>` , where keyfile is the associated private key.

Or you can directly copy the UTC file that lies in the keystore as explain here [import-account-from-one-geth-node-to-another-geth-node](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/49316/import-account-from-one-geth-node-to-another-geth-node)

Comment: Thanks 
The following account is imported from metamask with private key  i have changed my private key  in the comment  but i followed the same process
But it failed > geth account import b770ae3db608ab903d1f2a0b4dec4dc5
(anonymous): Line 1:6 Unexpected identifier (and 1 more errors)

Comment: you need to run this command from you OS command line not from the geth javascript console

Comment: i Tried it gave me 

geth account import  b770ae3db608b357c250ca0f8cd5
Fatal: Failed to load the private key: open b770ae3db608ab

Comment: b770ae3db608b357c250ca0f8cd5 is not a file containing your private key. I think you should read this link [link] (https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Managing-your-accounts)